# How long will it take to delete a row?

Tags: cassandra

I have a 2 node cassandra cluster with RF=2.
When a `delete from x where y` cql statement is issued - is it known how long it will take all nodes to delete the row?

What I see in one of the integration tests:
A row is deleted, the result of the deletion is tested with a `select * from y where id = xxx` statement. What I see is that sometimes the result is not null as expected and the deleted row is still found.

Is the correct approch to read with CL=2 to get the result I am expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. make sure that the servers time are in synch if you are using server side timestamp.
   Better use client side timestamp.

> Is the correct approch to read with CL=2 to get the result I am
>   expecting?

i assume you are using default consistecy while delete ie 1 and as 1+2 > 2 (ie W+R > N) in your case hence it is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Local to the replica it will be sub ms. The time is dominated in the time from `app->coordinator->replica->coordinator->app` network hops. Use quorum or local_quorum for consistency across sequential requests like that on *both* write and read.